Apache Ignite Idle Connection Timeout Not Working Consistently Between Linux and Windows Nodes
Problem Summary
Recently we migrated from Ignite: 2.8 to Ignite: 2.15 (Just for information)
We have an Apache Ignite cluster set up with two nodes: one running on a Linux server and the other on a Windows server. I'm encountering an issue where some TCP connections between these nodes are not being closed as expected, despite configuring the
idleConnectionTimeout in Ignite's TcpCommunicationSpi.
Cluster Setup and Configuration

Node A: Linux Server
Node B: Windows Server

Here's my current Ignite configuration:

IdleConnectionTimeout = 30s
FailureDetectionTimeout = 900sec
UsePairedConnections = true

Additional Network Settings:

Linux: TCP Keep-Alive Interval = 2 hours
Windows: TCP Keep-Alive Interval = 2 hours
Firewall: timeout = 1 hour

Issue Details
Expected Behavior:
Ignite should close idle TCP connections after 30 seconds of inactivity due to the idleConnectionTimeout setting.
Observed Behavior:

Some connections are correctly closed after 30 seconds of inactivity.
However, other connections remain open indefinitely and are only closed after the firewall's 1-hour timeout or the OS-level TCP keep-alive interval of 2 hours.
When these lingering connections are closed by the firewall or OS keep-alive, I see the following error in the logs when Ignite attempts to reuse these connections:


java.io.IOException: Connection timed out


After this error, Ignite cleans up the stale connection and re-establishes it, allowing communication to continue.

Logs Analysis
Here's a snippet of the logs for context:

Image showing that only single connection whose idleconnectiontimeout has not closed after the configured idle timeout.



Connection gets timed out

09:58:54:979603|2923-00119: [class org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi]: {ERROR} Action {Failed to process selector key [ses=GridSelectorNioSessionImpl [worker=DirectNioClientWorker [super=AbstractNioClientWorker [idx=3, bytesRcvd=450, bytesSent=42303, bytesRcvd0=0, bytesSent0=0, select=true, super=GridWorker [name=grid-nio-worker-tcp-comm-3, igniteInstanceName=TcpCommunicationSpi, finished=false, heartbeatTs=1730973533970, hashCode=1781702350, interrupted=false, runner=grid-nio-worker-tcp-comm-3-#26%TcpCommunicationSpi%]]], writeBuf=java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=32768 cap=32768], readBuf=java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=32768 cap=32768], inRecovery=null, outRecovery=GridNioRecoveryDescriptor [acked=220, resendCnt=0, rcvCnt=0, sentCnt=221, reserved=true, lastAck=0, nodeLeft=false, node=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=6bd0cb88-2519-4fa5-af61-c5ced899486e, consistentId=192.168.1.112,127.0.0.1:48900, addrs=ArrayList [192.168.1.112, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=null, discPort=48500, order=1, intOrder=1, lastExchangeTime=1730940088189, loc=false, ver=2.15.0#20230425-sha1:f98f7f35, isClient=false], connected=false, connectCnt=8, queueLimit=4096, reserveCnt=8, pairedConnections=true], closeSocket=true, outboundMessagesQueueSizeMetric=o.a.i.i.processors.metric.impl.LongAdderMetric@69a257d1, super=GridNioSessionImpl [locAddr=/11.88.130.14:34662, rmtAddr=192.168.1.112:48102, createTime=1730967723110, closeTime=0, bytesSent=9307, bytesRcvd=70, bytesSent0=0, bytesRcvd0=0, sndSchedTime=1730973524081, lastSndTime=1730972583303, lastRcvTime=1730973524081, readsPaused=false, filterChain=FilterChain[filters=[GridNioCodecFilter [parser=o.a.i.i.util.nio.GridDirectParser@7d0aac30, directMode=true], GridConnectionBytesVerifyFilter], accepted=false, markedForClose=false]]]} Thread {grid-nio-worker-tcp-comm-3-#26%TcpCommunicationSpi%}

java.io.IOException: Connection timed out  
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)  
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:47)  
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:330)  
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:284)  
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:259)  
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:417)  
at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$DirectNioClientWorker.processRead(GridNioServer.java:1351)  
at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.processSelectedKeysOptimized(GridNioServer.java:2526)  
at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.bodyInternal(GridNioServer.java:2281)  
at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.body(GridNioServer.java:1910)  
at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:125)  
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)

09:58:54:980744|0364-00119: [class org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi]: {WARN} Action {Client disconnected abruptly due to network connection loss or because the connection was left open on application shutdown. [cls=class o.a.i.i.util.nio.GridNioException, msg=Connection timed out]} Thread {grid-nio-worker-tcp-comm-3-#26%TcpCommunicationSpi%}
09:58:54:980987|0266-00119: [class org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi]: {DEBUG} Action {The node was disconnected [nodeId=6bd0cb88-2519-4fa5-af61-c5ced899486e, err=Connection timed out]} Thread {grid-nio-worker-tcp-comm-3-#26%TcpCommunicationSpi%}
09:58:54:984441|2105-00119: [class org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi]: {DEBUG} Action {The client was removed [nodeId=6bd0cb88-2519-4fa5-af61-c5ced899486e,  client=GridTcpNioCommunicationClient [ses=GridSelectorNioSessionImpl [worker=DirectNioClientWorker [super=AbstractNioClientWorker [idx=3, bytesRcvd=450, bytesSent=42303, bytesRcvd0=0, bytesSent0=0, select=true, super=GridWorker [name=grid-nio-worker-tcp-comm-3, igniteInstanceName=TcpCommunicationSpi, finished=false, heartbeatTs=1730973533970, hashCode=1781702350, interrupted=false, runner=grid-nio-worker-tcp-comm-3-#26%TcpCommunicationSpi%]]], writeBuf=java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=32768 cap=32768], readBuf=java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=32768 cap=32768], inRecovery=null, outRecovery=GridNioRecoveryDescriptor [acked=220, resendCnt=0, rcvCnt=0, sentCnt=221, reserved=true, lastAck=0, nodeLeft=false, node=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=6bd0cb88-2519-4fa5-af61-c5ced899486e, consistentId=192.168.1.112,127.0.0.1:48500, addrs=ArrayList [192.168.1.112, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=null, discPort=48500, order=1, intOrder=1, lastExchangeTime=1730940088189, loc=false, ver=2.15.0#20230425-sha1:f98f7f35, isClient=false], connected=false, connectCnt=8, queueLimit=4096, reserveCnt=8, pairedConnections=true], closeSocket=true, outboundMessagesQueueSizeMetric=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.metric.impl.LongAdderMetric@69a257d1, super=GridNioSessionImpl [locAddr=/11.88.130.14:34662, rmtAddr=192.168.1.112:48102, createTime=1730967723110, closeTime=1730973534976, bytesSent=9307, bytesRcvd=70, bytesSent0=0, bytesRcvd0=0, sndSchedTime=1730973524081, lastSndTime=1730972583303, lastRcvTime=1730973524081, readsPaused=false, filterChain=FilterChain[filters=[GridNioCodecFilter [parser=org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridDirectParser@7d0aac30, directMode=true], GridConnectionBytesVerifyFilter], accepted=false, markedForClose=true]], super=GridAbstractCommunicationClient [lastUsed=1730967723110, closed=true, connIdx=0]]].} Thread {grid-nio-worker-tcp-comm-3-#26%TcpCommunicationSpi%}
09:58:54:984517|0295-00119: [class org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi]: {DEBUG} Action {Session was closed but there are unacknowledged messages, will try to reconnect [rmtNode=6bd0cb88-2519-4fa5-af61-c5ced899486e]} Thread {grid-nio-worker-tcp-comm-3-#26%TcpCommunicationSpi%}
09:58:54:984899|0229-00121: [class org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi]: {DEBUG} Action {Recovery reconnect [rmtNode=6bd0cb88-2519-4fa5-af61-c5ced899486e]} Thread {tcp-comm-worker-#1%WebCluster%-#28%WebCluster%}09:58:54:984908|0250-00119: [class org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi]: {DEBUG} Action {The node was disconnected [nodeId=6bd0cb88-2519-4fa5-af61-c5ced899486e, err=null]} Thread {grid-nio-worker-tcp-comm-3-#26%TcpCommunicationSpi%}
09:58:54:984960|0269-00121: [class org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi]: {DEBUG} Action {The node client is going to reserve a connection [nodeId=6bd0cb88-2519-4fa5-af61-c5ced899486e, connIdx=0]} Thread {tcp-comm-worker-#1%WebCluster%-#28%WebCluster%}
09:58:54:985005|0295-00119: [class org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi]: {DEBUG} Action {Session was closed but there are unacknowledged messages, will try to reconnect [rmtNode=6bd0cb88-2519-4fa5-af61-c5ced899486e]} Thread {grid-nio-worker-tcp-comm-3-#26%TcpCommunicationSpi%} 


Wireshark Analysis

Using Wireshark, we observed that the last packet (for which an ACK was received) was sent either 1 hour or 2 hours before the connection timeout occurred. This indicates that no data packets were exchanged for an extended period before the connection was forcibly closed. The timing aligns with the firewall and OS-level keep-alive intervals, suggesting that these idle connections are not being actively used until the external timeout triggers.
Given this prolonged inactivity, it's unclear why Ignite's idleConnectionTimeout of 30 seconds is not being applied to close these connections sooner.

Environment Details

Apache Ignite Version: 2.15
JDK Version: 17
Operating Systems:

Node A: Linux
Node B: Windows Server



Questions

Why are some connections not closing after the configured idleConnectionTimeout of 30 seconds?
Are there additional Ignite settings or OS configurations I should tweak to ensure all idle connections are closed as expected?

